# Deserializing a json string to C#.net classes using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (v 4.0.8.14612)

Tags: c#-4.0, teamcity, deserialization, json.net

In my web app, I have written some tests to test my deserializing logic that parses a json string in to my C# classes. These tests runs fine on my computer, but they fail on our CI environment with this error message:

```
Test(s) failed. System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert' threw an exception. ----> System.Security.VerificationException : Operation could destabilize the runtime.
```

One json string example is this (from the test class):

```
private const string MatrikkelJson = "{'Gaardsnummer':'9','Bruksnummer':'9','Festenummer':'8','Seksjonsnummer':'8','BlankAllowed':'False','AttrType':'Matrikkel'}";
```

This string should be deserialized to this class:

```
public class MatrikkelDTO : AttributeBaseDTO
    {
        public string Gaardsnummer { get; set; }
        public string Bruksnummer { get; set; }
        public string Festenummer { get; set; }
        public string Seksjonsnummer { get; set; }
    }

public class AttributeBaseDTO
    {        
        public bool BlankAllowed { get; set; }     
        public string AttrType { get; set; }
    }
```

The method that deserializes the json string works like this:
I first deserialize the baseobject to get the AttrType property. Using that information I deserialize the json string to the specific type (I have several classes that inherits from AttributBaseDTO.

```
public AttributeValidationHandlerResponse ValidateAttribute(string serializedObject)
        {
            var response = new AttributeValidationHandlerResponse();
            response.Result = false;
            //hack... this handler gets called when opening newdocument.aspx. don't know why.
            if (serializedObject.Contains("function"))
            {                
                response.Message = "";
                return response;
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(serializedObject))
            {                
                response.Message = "attributeobject";
                return response;
            }

            var message = "";
            var attributeBase = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AttributeBaseDTO>(serializedObject);

if (attributeBase.AttrType == "Matrikkel")
            {
                var attribute = ConvertJsonStringToAttribute<MatrikkelDTO>(serializedObject);
                response = ValidateMatrikkel(attribute);
            }
            return response;
        }

        internal T ConvertJsonStringToAttribute<T>(string serializedObject)
        {            
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedObject);
        }
```

But I can't figure out why it works on my machine and not on the build server.
I'm using VS 2010, asp.net 4.0, net framework 4.0. Test framework is nunit 2.5.5

Any clues anyone?

Comment: I logged on the team city build agent server and ran the tests using nunit ui. All tests passed. That is kind of strange.. Is the exception related to how Teamcity runs the tests some how?

Comment: I have a similar problem, different code but same issue. I have even run the tests with the TC NUnit Launcher and it succeeds... But fails when TC runs it... Using same user

Comment: Ensure you don't have any TypeMock products installed... That was my issue.